# MongoDB insert unique object into array (by author field)

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I:

- Update an object in the `reviews` array, if an existing object with the same `author` exists
- Insert a new object otherwise

(In other words: update a review if the author has already written one, and create a new one if they haven't)

Document structure:

```py
{
    "_id": "(book id)",
    "title": "Title",
    "author": "Author",
    "reviews": [{
        "author": "(user id)",
        "rating": 4
    }],
}
```

This is what I've tried so far -- it only updates:

```py
db.books.update_one(
    {"_id": ObjectId(book_id)},
    {"$set": {"reviews.$[elem]": {  # or $push etc.
        "author": user_id, "rating": rating}}},
    array_filters=[{"elem.author": user_id}])
```

Alternatively I have also tried `result.modified_count == 0: then insert` but this would insert a duplicate if the previous rating is the same as the new one (hence not updating anything and `result.modified_count == 0`)

Sorry for another similar question! Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**:

From the [$addToSet operator page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/):

"...you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a duplicate of an existing array element."

However I'm still interested if anyone has a way to do this (it doesn't have to be in one query)!

Answer (score 1):

From reading the docs, I would try [find and modify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) with a condition on `reviews.author`, then an update with an [update operator expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) using `$push` on `reviews`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion! My issue is still within the `$push` operator, how do I push while "checking" the `author` field? Such that `{author: 1, rating: 2}` would replace `{author: 1, rating: 3}` (according to `$push`, these are different -- hence it would insert another review into the array.)

Comment: You push when there is no review, right? What do you nee to check?